# How to make bootstrap card body paragraph on the same position regardless of card title

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pulling a list of news articles from the database and I'm putting them in a bootstrap card. 
 My problem is when the news title is longer obviously the paragraph will be in a different position, 
 
 look at the **picture** to better understand the problem 
 I have tried to set different margins and padding styles but I know it needs to be dynamic depending on the title size but what's the best possible way to do that?  
 Here is my code.

```
<div class="item card ">
  <img src="public/img/news/<?= $singleNews['news_image']; ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="blog">
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="passion.html">
      <h5 class="card-title ">
        <?=   $singleNews['news_title']; ?>
      </h5>
    </a>
    <div class="card-paragraph ">
      <p>
        <?php
                            //    $shortDetail = strlen($singleNews['news_short_detail']) > 70 ? substr($singleNews['news_short_detail'],0,70):$singleNews['news_short_detail'];
                                echo  $singleNews['news_short_detail']; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn_3">read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be a solution to cut the title after a maximum of characters?

Comment: OPTION1: set `min-height` of title tag and align it to `center` via `line-height` or `flex`. OPTION2: set specific `height` and then `font-size` to `vw` unit so that it adjust it self with `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @Awais make it an answer. 
min-height solved the problem

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion @Lawa i added my answer you can edit what suits best for you in that Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options

**OPTION1:** set `min-height` of title tag and align it to `center` via `line-height` or `flex`.

**OPTION2:** set specific `height` and then `font-size` to `vw` unit so that it adjust it self with `overflow:hidden`